# Where are logs for postgres 10.2 on mac

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgres 10.2 with brew on mac

My postgres.conf is

`log_destination = 'stderr'
 logging_collector = off
 log_statement = 'all'`

I started it as blow

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`

However I cannot find the logs at /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log or somewhere else.

Any help?

Comment: https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/11/12/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't change `log_directory` from the default, the logs should be in `/usr/local/var/postgres/log` (on PostgreSQL versions before v10, it is `pg_log` rather than `log`).

But since you set `logging_collector = off`, the log is not redirected from standard error. You should change that setting.

Note that some distributions manage logging by starting PostgreSQL with `pg_ctl -l <logfile>` rather than setting `logging_collector = on`; examine the startup script for details.

Comment: But I have the same setting (log_destination = 'stderr' and logging_collector = off) on Ubuntu and I have /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log. Any idea why?

Comment: I turned on logging_collector and did not change log_directory and I got my log at /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_log/postgresql-2018-02-21_133408.log, but not /usr/local/var/postgres/logs. Any idea?

Comment: Yes -- that is because you are using a PostgreSQL version older than v10.

Comment: The postgres on ubuntu is v10.1. The one on mac is 10.2

Comment: The default value for log_directory is pg_log. I don't see /usr/local/var/postgres/logs in postgresql.conf. Any idea?

Comment: I have extended the answer in an attempt to cover that.

Comment: The postgres on ubuntu is v10.1. I started it like this "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf". log_destination and logging_collector are default values in postgresql.conf. However I still see /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log. Any idea why?

Comment: What do you get for `logging_collector` if you run `SHOW ALL;` in psql? Maybe it was set somewhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165614/discussion-between-haibin-liu-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: Try the following:
`SELECT setting, context, source, boot_val, reset_val, sourcefile FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'logging_collector';`

Comment: jarvis2_backend_production=> SELECT setting, context, source, boot_val, reset_val, sourcefile FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'logging_collector'; 
setting | context | source | boot_val | reset_val | sourcefile 
---------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------ 
off | postmaster | default | off | off | 
(1 row)

Comment: Then it must have been started with `-l` or standard error has been redirected.